# Get Name of User From ID - Discord JDA

Tags: java, discord, discord-jda

I get a **User** from `User.fromID(long id)`

`User u = User.fromID(123456);`

I then want to get the name of that user. So I use `User.getName()`

`String name = u.getName();`

But then I get an error.

```
[JDA MainWS-ReadThread] ERROR JDA - One of the EventListeners had an uncaught exception
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: This User instance only wraps an ID. Other operations are unsupported
    at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.entities.UserById.unsupported(UserById.java:78)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.entities.UserById.getName(UserById.java:85)
    at bot.Profile.<init>(Profile.java:19)
    at files.Profiles.handleUser(Profiles.java:17)
    at bot.Chat.onMessageReceived(Chat.java:19)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.api.hooks.ListenerAdapter.onEvent(ListenerAdapter.java:430)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.api.hooks.InterfacedEventManager.handle(InterfacedEventManager.java:96)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.hooks.EventManagerProxy.handleInternally(EventManagerProxy.java:82)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.hooks.EventManagerProxy.handle(EventManagerProxy.java:69)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.JDAImpl.handleEvent(JDAImpl.java:150)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.handle.MessageCreateHandler.handleInternally(MessageCreateHandler.java:122)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.handle.SocketHandler.handle(SocketHandler.java:36)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.requests.WebSocketClient.onDispatch(WebSocketClient.java:948)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.requests.WebSocketClient.onEvent(WebSocketClient.java:835)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.requests.WebSocketClient.handleEvent(WebSocketClient.java:813)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.requests.WebSocketClient.onBinaryMessage(WebSocketClient.java:986)
    at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.ListenerManager.callOnBinaryMessage(ListenerManager.java:385)
    at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.ReadingThread.callOnBinaryMessage(ReadingThread.java:276)
    at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.ReadingThread.handleBinaryFrame(ReadingThread.java:996)
    at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.ReadingThread.handleFrame(ReadingThread.java:755)
    at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.ReadingThread.main(ReadingThread.java:108)
    at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.ReadingThread.runMain(ReadingThread.java:64)
    at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.WebSocketThread.run(WebSocketThread.java:45)
```

How can I get the name of a **User** that only wraps an **ID**?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: what do I need to explain more?

Comment: @KelumSampathEdirisinghe The **User** class is a part of the discord JDA
https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/entities/User.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a [JDA](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/JDA.html) instance and use [retrieveUserById](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/JDA.html#retrieveUserById(long)) instead.

Example:

```java
jda.retrieveUserById(userId)
   .map(User::getName)
   .queue(name -> {
   // use name here
       System.out.println("The user has the name " + name);
   });
```